# Ext.NET DirectMethod throws "... has no method" error

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I am trying to assign the handler on the back end. So I currently have:

```
    foreach (Component comp in leftComponenets)
    {
        if (comp is TextField)
        {
            ((TextField)comp).Listeners.Focus.Handler = "Ext.net.DirectMethods.clickOnObject();";
        }
    }
```

in the document.aspx.cs file. It generates the components to be added to the left panel. It is necessary to do on the back end because this is generated dynamically during page render (not a finite number of elements). The method that I am trying to call is:

```
[DirectMethod]
public void clickOnObject()
{
    Response.Write("hwerlkjasdf;ljasdf");
}
```

However it seems like the method does not get added to the Ext.net.DirectMethods object in the javascript so thus it cannot be called. I am not sure how to make the linking work at this stage. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the fact that my function is in a different file and not inline with the page itself? I have looked over a number of examples and none seem to be of any help.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With a [DirectMethod] you cannot write directly to the Response stream. Based on the code sample you provided above, if you change it show a Notification window it should work.

**Example**

```
X.Msg.Notify("Message", "hwerlkjasdf;ljasdf").Show();
```

Hope this helps.